# Communication between Android and EC2 with RDS

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance on AWS configured with Apache tomcat 8 and java. 
Following some tutorials from here, I can create one .war of my Web Service in eclipse and put it inside webapps folder of tomcat in my EC2 instance. 
I am able to access this services from the IP address of EC2 with the specific port and .war file name. 
For example:

```
IPADDRESS:8080/MyApplication.
```

And everything seems to work fine, I can open the services and see the wsdl files. My Web Service (in .war file) is configured for make a connection with a RDS instance from amazon. 
The connection itself is ok, I tested in localhost a direct connection with RDS from Android. 
But, when I try to connect with services that I put in EC2 (from there
the connection with my RDS is created) from Android, no data returns and I get a Null Pointer. 
The link that I used to make a connection with EC2 from Android is the Public IP of EC2 and the port (8080), followed by the specific path of wsdl file.
For example:

```
http://99.999.999.99:8080/MyApplication/services/SomeServiceName?wsdl
```

I am using the KSOAP library to consume web service on Android side and I 
have no idea of the reason that I don't get data from EC2 instance.

All methods in the web service and the comsumption in  Android works fine, I tested all in local host.

- I tested all my methods of web service using SOAP UI, and all of them is working
- For test the RDS instance that contains my DB, I run the web service in localhost with tomcat 8 and the communication *Android ->  My PC (localhost) -> RDS instance (My DB)* is working.

The problem are when I try to change the communication line from:

```
 *Android ->  My PC (localhost) -> RDS instance (My DB)*
```

TO:

```
 *Android ->  EC2 instance -> RDS instance (My DB)*
```

Again, in EC2 I make the deploy of my web service.

- I use the same security group for RDS and EC2:

*Inbound rules:*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUdyl.png

*Outbound rules:*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4gLc.png

Comment: can you test your webservice using the public ip in a remote computer ?, or using localhost in the ec2 instance ?.     can you test your web service using soap ui for example ?    - Did you configure your security groups in the ec2 instance? maybe the port 8080 is not accessible from  anywhere, try to give us a little bit more information

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I make an edite, take a look.

Comment: Is another name, and yes, is the same. I don't see the single "p", I will edit, thanks.

Comment: 1 First, download an app to ping ip address in your smartphone, 2 check that your smartphone see the public ip address of your ec2 instance, 3 If it can't see the ip address try to use the public DNS of the ec2 instance instead of the public ip address, 4 make the soap ui tests to your ec2 instance and not to your computer, 5 if you can execute your test cases it means that your ec2 instance and your application are working fine, and it is a problem related of your android application, 6 let us know the result of the steps in order to try to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.

I did the following:
I connected to my ECB2 instance and open the tomcat 8 log, so I saw that the error was ClassNotFoundException, related to Postgres (my engine DB).

I opened my web service eclipse project and saw this (stupid) error:

*The .jar postgres driver was in that lib folder:*

[image]

*Instead of that folder:*

[image]

So, basically, when I did the deploy of my Web service in EC2 instance the postgres driver does not go together.

Thanks for the help, I hope that helps someone else.